# Open UIImagePickerController in landscape

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

I am trying to present UIImagePickerController in landscape mode for iPhone, as my application supports only landscape mode.Which works fine with iOS 11.But whenever I run my application in iOS 10.3.3 it gets crash the same time with error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES' * First throw call stack:**
```

Comment: Subclass UIImagePickerController and implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and  `shouldAutorotate` method

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension of UIImagePickerController like below

```
extension UIImagePickerController
    {
        override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
                return true
        }
        override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
                return .all
        }
   }
```

Hope that will help you